# SharePoint communication (modern) site anonymous authentication not working

Tags: anonymous-authentication, 2019, communication-site

I created a SharePoint communication (modern) site and enable anonymous access over the web application and site collection level and when anonymous user login to this site it shows a pop-up for authentication.